# C-Free and MySQL connect

Tags: c++, mysql

Sorry if my English is bad, I tried to connect to mysql using cfree 5 and it returns [Error] `D:\C-FREE~1\mingw\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lD:\DoAn1\lib\libmysql.lib` but I already linked it . Could anyone tell me what I should to do to fix this problem? 
[Problem Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jMTd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `-l` parameter used to set the library name with a filename and set the library path with `-L` parameter.
**Example**:
`-lmysql -LD:\DoAn1\lib`